# Linq group query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this model data

```
 public class Product
    {
      public int ProductId { get; set; }
      public string CategoryName { get; set; }
      public string CategoryValue { get; set; }

    }
```

Data

```json
[
  {
    "productId": 1,
    "categoryName": "A",
    "categoryValue": "AV"
  },
  {
    "productId": 1,
    "categoryName": "B",
    "categoryValue": "BV"
  },
  {
    "productId": 1,
    "categoryName": "C",
    "categoryValue": "CV"
  },
  {
    "productId": 2,
    "categoryName": "B",
    "categoryValue": "BV"
  },
  {
    "productId": 3,
    "categoryName": "C",
    "categoryValue": "CV"
  }
]
```

I want to transform into that model through linq

```
 public class ProductwithCategory
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> allCategoriesWithvalue { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }
```

Transformed data (finial result)

```
[
  {
    "productId": 1,
    "allCategoriesWithvalue": {
      "A": "AV",
      "B": "BV",
      "C": "CV"
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": 2,
    "allCategoriesWithvalue": {
      "A": "",
      "B": "BV",
      "C": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": 3,
    "allCategoriesWithvalue": {
      "A": "",
      "B": "",
      "C": "CV"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to c# linq query for that

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You didn't post anything that can be queried, or any kind of real data. Only things that look somewhat like JSON without being valid JSON. If you have a `List<Product>`, did you try grouping by ProductID? After that you can use `ToDictionary` on the grouped items to get the categories

Comment: Perhaps `data.GroupBy(p=>p.ProductId).Select(g=>new ProductwithCategory{ ProductId=g.Key,AllCategories=g.ToDictionary(it=>it.CategoryName,it=>TCategoryValue)})`?

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos , I want every category name in each product.
for ProductId: 2 Category A and C should have with blank value as below 
"allCategoriesWithvalue": {
      "A": "",
      "B": "BV",
      "C": ""
    }

Comment: Where would you get "every" category? Is there a list of them? An enum? What's the actual logic and what did you actually try? It seems the only thing missing is adding the missing categories.

Comment: Add the logic in the question itself. Don't make people guess. Also make it *easy* for people to test your data. I guess most people didn't even tried parsing the JSON string. I created a working script, parsing the JSON string only to notice the missing categories at the end. I gave up at this point

Comment: We need to fetch distinct category from same data object like this 
var distinctCategories = data.Select(col => col.CategoryName).Distinct();

Comment: Sorry @PanagiotisKanavos for that, due to my poor English it happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an empty value when the category is missing you left join with a distinct collection of the categories.

```
var l = new List<Product>()
{
    new Product() { ProductId = 1, CategoryName = "A", CategoryValue = "AV" },
    new Product() { ProductId = 1, CategoryName = "B", CategoryValue = "BV" },
    new Product() { ProductId = 1, CategoryName = "C", CategoryValue = "CV" },
    new Product() { ProductId = 2, CategoryName = "B", CategoryValue = "BV" },
    new Product() { ProductId = 3, CategoryName = "C", CategoryValue = "CV" },
};
var categories = l.Select(x => x.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList();
var r = l
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
    .Select(x => new ProductwithCategory()
    {
        ProductId = x.Key,
        allCategoriesWithvalue = (from c in categories
                                 join p in x on c equals p.CategoryName into ps
                                 from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new { c, p?.CategoryValue }).ToDictionary(x => x.c, x => x.CategoryValue ?? "")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must `group by ProductId first` and consider `productId as key`. Then select `CategoryName` and `CategoryValue` in a `dictionary called allCategoriesWithvalue`.

```
products.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
        .Select(group => new ProductwithCategory
        {
          ProductId = group.Key,
         allCategoriesWithvalue = group.ToDictionary(p => p.CategoryName, p => p.CategoryValue)
        }).ToList();
```

[Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pDRs6K)